# Refine on optional property in union type with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a union type `Entity` consisting of two different types, `Door` and `Handle`. The property rotation exists in one of the sub types, but not the other. This seems to mean that I can't refine on that property, but get the error `Cannot get entity.rotation because property rotation is missing in`Handle`[1].`

I know it's missing, that's why I'm trying to check if it's there.

```
type Door = {
  id: number,
  rotation: number
}

type Handle = {
  id: number
}

type Entity = Handle | Door;

const foo = (entity: Entity): number => {
  if (entity.rotation) {
    return entity.rotation;
  } else {
   return 2;
  }
}
```

**Cannot get `entity.rotation` because property `rotation` is missing in `Handle` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAiccATmALxgDeqYYAlgCYBcYAdgK4C2ARnqQA0dMKTgYAhhgZx2bLnwGoAvumz4wACQnsmMAlVr1m8nv1Iq1uAgFF207JS069BAD5ESpANzoAxrIAzhhgUCROABR49gzYbHYOWACUporkFAB8NCIMUGBRMdgAdGKS0rJJ2fT0pHgYnKTsYNGJJeJSMuy+9MrNMIEERjV1DU0ATN1gqqpAA).**

Is there a way to refine where a property exists or not in the type?

[Running example in the flow editor](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAiccATmALxgDeqYYAlgCYBcYAdgK4C2ARnqQA0dMKTgYAhhgZx2bLnwGoAvumz4wACQnsmMAlVr1m8nv1Iq1uAgFF207JS069BAD5ESpANzoAxrIAzhhgUCROABR49gzYbHYOWACUporkFAB8NCIMUGBRMdgAdGKS0rJJ2fT0pHgYnKTsYNGJJeJSMuy+9MrNMIEERjV1DU0ATN1gqqpAA)

Comment: FYI you could just check if `rotation` is a `number`: `if (typeof entity.rotation === 'number')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not declaring Handle as a strict type you are telling Flow that it may contains the rotation properties.

```
type Door = {
  id: number,
  rotation: number
}

type Handle = {|
  id: number
|}

type Entity = Handle | Door;

const foo = (entity: Entity): number => {
  if (entity.rotation) {
    return entity.rotation;
  } else {
   return 2;
  }
}
```

[Flow editor](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAiccATmALxgDeqYYAlgCYBcYAdgK4C2ARnqQA0dMKTgYAhhgZx2bLnwGoAvumz4wACQnsmMAlWoAfEc3k9+pVEdWZcBAKLtp2Slp16CRoiVIBudABjWQBnDDAoEjcACjxnBmw2JxcsAEpzRXIKAD4aUygwWPjsADoxSWlZVLz6elI8DE5SdjA4lLLxKRl2APplVpgQglpa+sbmsAAmXrBVVSA)

[Flow documentation link](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types)

Comment: Yes, but I'm checking for if the property exists. What I am wondering is if there is a way to refine if the property exists in the type

Comment: You are checking if the property exists on objects that are not strict, this is a valid declaration:


`const _handle: Handle = { id: 42, rotation: 2};`

Quote from the documentation

With exact object types, we cannot have additional properties, so the objects conflict with one another and we are able to distinguish which is which.

Comment: so I can only check for a property if the type is strict?

Comment: @stinaq, no, you can check for properties on non-strict objects. However, if you're trying to refine the type of a disjoint union, you either need a shared property across the objects types (probably the better way) or you need to be using exact objects as in sanghin's answer